# Find the location of a character in string

Tags: regex, string, r

I would like to find the location of a character in a string.

Say: `string = "the2quickbrownfoxeswere2tired"`

I would like the function to return `4` and `24` -- the character location of the `2`s in `string`.

Comment: Why use a regex? Doesn't r has an `.indexOf()` or something?

Comment: I doubt it. The developers were Nixers and assumed everyone knew regex. R's string handling is kind of kludgy.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You can use `gregexpr`

```
 gregexpr(pattern ='2',"the2quickbrownfoxeswere2tired")


[[1]]
[1]  4 24
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 1 1
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

or perhaps `str_locate_all` from package `stringr` which is a wrapper for <s>`gregexpr`</s> `stringi::stri_locate_all` (as of `stringr` version 1.0)

```
library(stringr)
str_locate_all(pattern ='2', "the2quickbrownfoxeswere2tired")

[[1]]
     start end
[1,]     4   4
[2,]    24  24
```

note that you could simply use `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
stri_locate_all(pattern = '2', "the2quickbrownfoxeswere2tired", fixed = TRUE)
```

Another option in base `R` would be something like

```
lapply(strsplit(x, ''), function(x) which(x == '2'))
```

should work (given a character vector `x`)

Comment: how can we extract the integers from the lists/objects returned by your first 3 solutions?

Comment: Use `regexpr` instead of `gregexpr` to get the integers easily. Or use `unlist` on the output as indicated in another answer below.

Answer (score 45):

Here's another straightforward alternative.

```
> which(strsplit(string, "")[[1]]=="2")
[1]  4 24
```

Comment: Can you explain what the `[[1]]` does?

Comment: @francoiskroll, [[1]] represents the first element of the list.

Answer (score 22):

You can make the output just 4 and 24 using unlist:

```
unlist(gregexpr(pattern ='2',"the2quickbrownfoxeswere2tired"))
[1]  4 24
```

Answer (score 4):

find the position of the nth occurrence of str2 in str1(same order of parameters as Oracle SQL INSTR), returns 0 if not found

```
instr <- function(str1,str2,startpos=1,n=1){
    aa=unlist(strsplit(substring(str1,startpos),str2))
    if(length(aa) < n+1 ) return(0);
    return(sum(nchar(aa[1:n])) + startpos+(n-1)*nchar(str2) )
}


instr('xxabcdefabdddfabx','ab')
[1] 3
instr('xxabcdefabdddfabx','ab',1,3)
[1] 15
instr('xxabcdefabdddfabx','xx',2,1)
[1] 0
```

Answer (score 2):

To only find the **first** locations, use `lapply()` with `min()`:

```
my_string <- c("test1", "test1test1", "test1test1test1")

unlist(lapply(gregexpr(pattern = '1', my_string), min))
#> [1] 5 5 5

# or the readable tidyverse form
my_string %>%
  gregexpr(pattern = '1') %>%
  lapply(min) %>%
  unlist()
#> [1] 5 5 5
```

To only find the **last** locations, use `lapply()` with `max()`:

```
unlist(lapply(gregexpr(pattern = '1', my_string), max))
#> [1]  5 10 15

# or the readable tidyverse form
my_string %>%
  gregexpr(pattern = '1') %>%
  lapply(max) %>%
  unlist()
#> [1]  5 10 15
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `grep` as well:

```
grep('2', strsplit(string, '')[[1]])
#4 24
```