# Find location of $ in string

Tags: regex, string, r

Based on the advice here: [Find location of character in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249562/find-location-of-character-in-string), I tried this:

```
> gregexpr(pattern ='$',"data.frame.name$variable.name")
[[1]]
[1] 30
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 0
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

But it didn't work; note:

```
> nchar("data.frame.name$variable.name")
[1] 29
```

How do you find the location of `$` in this string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `$` is the end-of-string marker in the regex. Try this instead:

```
> gregexpr(pattern ='\\$',"data.frame.name$variable.name")
[[1]]
[1] 16
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 1
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

... which gives the right answer - i.e. `16`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one solution using `strsplit` and `which`

```
> which(strsplit("data.frame.name$variable.name", "")[[1]]=="$")
[1] 16
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a very simple, clever solution.

Comment: BTW, you should add this as an answer to the other thread; it's more straightforward than the existing answer.

Comment: FWIW, I gave the check to Simon b/c he also explained why my code wasn't working, but I'll use this solution since it's simpler.

Comment: Although Jilber's solution is a nice alternative, I would go for Simon's approach. Given that the reader has some experience with R, the code with `gregexpr` is easier to understand and is most likely more efficient. I assume that `gregexpr` just iterates through the string, whereas `strsplit` splits the whole string into single characters and then stores the result. Although performance may not be an issue here, I still consider `gregexpr` as the better approach.