# extract character preceding first dot in a string

Tags: regex, r, string

I would like to extract the character preceding the first dot in a column of strings.  I can do so with the code below.  Although, the code seems overly complex and I had to resort to a `for-loop`.  Is there an easier way?  I particularly am interested in a `regex` solution.

Note that finding the last number in each string will not work with my real data, although that approach would work with this example.

Thank you for any advice.

```
my.data <- read.table(text = '
     my.string  state
     .........    A
     1........    B
     112......    C
     11111....    D
     1111113..    E
     111111111    F
     111111111    G
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

desired.result <- c(NA,1,2,1,3,NA,NA)
```

Identify the position of the first dot:

```
my.data$first.dot <- apply(my.data, 1, function(x) {     
                                as.numeric(gregexpr("\\.", x['my.string'])[[1]])[1]
                          })
```

Split strings:

```
split.strings <- t(apply(my.data, 1, function(x) { (strsplit(x['my.string'], '')[[1]]) } ))

my.data$revised.first.dot <- ifelse(my.data$first.dot < 2, NA, my.data$first.dot-1)
```

Extract the character preceding the first dot:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(my.data)) {
     my.data$character.before.dot[i] <- split.strings[i,my.data$revised.first.dot[i]]
}

my.data

#   my.string state first.dot revised.first.dot character.before.dot
# 1 .........     A         1                NA                 <NA>
# 2 1........     B         2                 1                    1
# 3 112......     C         4                 3                    2
# 4 11111....     D         6                 5                    1
# 5 1111113..     E         8                 7                    3
# 6 111111111     F        -1                NA                 <NA>
# 7 111111111     G        -1                NA                 <NA>
```

Here is a related post:

[find location of character in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249562/find-location-of-character-in-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a base R solution with `ifelse`:

```
res <- regexpr("[^.](?=\\.)", my.data$my.string, perl = TRUE)
ifelse(res < 1, NA, as.integer(regmatches(my.data$my.string, res)))
# [1] NA  2  1  3  1 NA NA
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the below regex and don't forget to enable `perl=TRUE` parameter.

```
^[^.]*?\K[^.](?=\.)
```

In R, the regex would be like,

```
^[^.]*?\\K[^.](?=\\.)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jM7xI3/2)

```
> library(stringr)
> as.numeric(str_extract(my.data$my.string, perl("^[^.]*?\\K[^.](?=\\.)")))
[1] NA  1  2  1  3 NA NA
```

**Pattern Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `[^.]*?` Non-greedy match of any character upto the first dot.
- `\K` Discards previously matched characters.
- `[^.]` Character we are going to match must not be a dot.
- `(?=\.)` And this character must be followed by a dot. So it matches the character which exists just before to the first dot.

Comment: Nice, I keep forgetting about `\K`.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest regex would be `^([^.])+(?=\.)`:

```
^      # Start of string
(      # Start of group 1
 [^.]  # Match any character except .
)+     # Repeat as many times as needed, overwriting the previous match
(?=\.) # Assert the next character is a .
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/jM7xI3/1).

The contents of group 1 will be your desired character. I'm not much of an R guy, but according to [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com), the following should work:

```
matches <- regexpr("^([^.])+(?=\\.)", my.data, perl=TRUE);
result <- attr(matches, "capture.start")[,1]
attr(result, "match.length") <- attr(matches, "capture.length")[,1]
regmatches(my.data, result)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the example, it was all `digits` and `.`

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_extract(my.data$my.string, perl('\\d(?=\\.)')))
#[1] NA  1  2  1  3 NA NA
```

Or using `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
as.numeric(stri_extract(my.data$my.string, regex='\\d(?=\\.)'))
#[1] NA  1  2  1  3 NA NA
```

If it is for a `general` case:

```
as.numeric(str_extract(my.data$my.string, perl('[^.](?=\\.)')))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[^.](?=\\.)
```

You can simply do this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/qB0jV1/26

Comment: I did not down vote, but I am having a little trouble obtaining the `desired.result` with any of these answers.  In your case, I think `\.` should be `\\.`

Comment: It returns the position of characters.  Ideally I can obtain the vector `desired.result` in base `R`.  I just need to figure out how to do that and I will be set.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @vks op didn't talk about unicode strings, and he provided as his example data.

Comment: @AvinashRaj So far I have not up-voted or down-voted anything on this post.  I will probably up-vote each answer once I figure out how to obtain the vector `desired.result` in base `R`.

Answer (score 1):

Using [rex](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rex/index.html) may make this type of task a little simpler.

```
my.data <- read.table(text = '
     my.string  state
     .........    A
     1........    B
     112......    C
     11111....    D
     1111113..    E
     111111111    F
     111111111    G
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(rex)

re_matches(my.data$my.string,
  rex(capture(except(".")), "."))$'1'

#> [1] NA  "1" "2" "1" "3" NA  NA
```