# r substring wildcard search to find text

Tags: r, substring, wildcard

I have a data.frame column that has values such as below. I want to use each cell and create two columns- num1 and num2 such that num1=everything before "-" and num2=everything between "-" and "."

I am thinking of using gregexpr function as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249562/find-location-of-character-in-string) and write a for loop to iterate over each row. Is there a faster way to do this?

```
60-150.PNG
300-12.PNG

employee <- c('60-150.PNG','300-12.PNG')
employ.data <- data.frame(employee)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
library(tidyr)
extract(employ.data, employee, into=c('num1', 'num2'),
                    '([^-]*)-([^.]*)\\..*', convert=TRUE)
#   num1 num2
#1   60  150
#2  300   12
```

Or

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(employ.data)[, tstrsplit(employee, '[-.]', type.convert=TRUE)[-3]]
#    V1  V2
#1:  60 150
#2: 300  12
```

Or based on @rawr's comment

```
 read.table(text=gsub('-|.PNG', ' ', employ.data$employee),
           col.names=c('num1', 'num2'))
 #   num1 num2
 #1   60  150
 #2  300   12
```

#### Update

To keep the original column

```
extract(employ.data, employee, into=c('num1', 'num2'), remove=FALSE,
        '([^-]*)-([^.]*)\\..*', convert=TRUE)
#    employee num1 num2
#1 60-150.PNG   60  150
#2 300-12.PNG  300   12
```

Or

```
 setDT(employ.data)[, paste0('num', 1:2) := tstrsplit(employee, 
             '[-.]', type.convert=TRUE)[-3]]
 #     employee num1 num2
 #1: 60-150.PNG   60  150
 #2: 300-12.PNG  300   12
```

Or

```
 cbind(employ.data, read.table(text=gsub('-|.PNG', ' ', 
     employ.data$employee),col.names=c('num1', 'num2')))
 #    employee num1 num2
 #1 60-150.PNG   60  150
 #2 300-12.PNG  300   12
```

Comment: akrun taught me this one `read.table(text = gsub('-|.PNG', ' ', dat$employee))`

Comment: how would i assign column names in case of read.table(text = gsub('-|.PNG', ' ', dat$employee))?

Comment: try `read.table(text=gsub('-|.PNG', ' ', employ.data$employee), col.names=c('num1', 'num2'))`  Or use `setNames(read.table(text=gsub('-|.PNG', ' ', employ.data$employee)), paste0('num', 1:2))`

Comment: perfect. Please modify your answer and i will accept it

Comment: any way to add 2 new columns to the the original data.frame?

Comment: @user2543622  Did you mean to keep the original column also in the dataset

Comment: yes. the original data.frame will get 2 new columns num1 and num2. Old columns will remain as it is

Comment: @user2543622  Updated the post, please check if it helps

Comment: it works. but i had to change "cbind(employ.data,..." to "cbind(employ$data,.."

Comment: @user2543622  That is strange.  It works with R 3.2.0. though

Answer (score 3):

You can try `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(employ.data, "employee", "-|.PNG", fixed = FALSE)
#    employee_1 employee_2
# 1:         60        150
# 2:        300         12
```

Since you mention `gregexpr`, you can probably try something like:

```
do.call(rbind, 
        regmatches(as.character(employ.data$employee), 
                   gregexpr("-|.PNG", employ.data$employee), 
                   invert = TRUE))[, -3]
     [,1]  [,2] 
[1,] "60"  "150"
[2,] "300" "12"
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option using `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
data.frame(type.convert(stri_split_regex(employee, "[-.]", simplify = TRUE)[, -3]))
#    X1  X2
# 1  60 150
# 2 300  12
```

Answer (score 2):

Or with the simple `gsub`.

```
gsub("-.*", "", employ.data$employee) # substitute everything after - with nothing
gsub(".*-(.*)\\..*", "\\1", employ.data$employee) #keep only anything between - and .
```

Answer (score 1):

The `strsplit` function will give you what you're looking for, output to a list.

```
employee <- c('60-150.PNG','300-12.PNG')
strsplit(employee, "[-]")

##Output:

[[1]]
[1] "60"      "150.PNG"

[[2]]
[1] "300"    "12.PNG"
```

Note the second argument to `strsplit` is a regex value, not just a character to split on, so more complicated regexp can be used.

Comment: This should be probably something like `data.frame(lapply(strsplit(sub("\\..*", "", employee), "-"), type.convert))`