# Double quotes within character strings

Tags: r, string, character, gsub, double-quotes

I want to do two thing:

1) I want to create a character string with a double quote inside. An example in R would look like follows:

```
x <- 'vjghvbh"kljnj"kjbn"jk'
[1] "vjghvbh\"kljnj\"kjbn\"jk"
```

**Question 1: How could I create such a character string without the backslash inside?**

I tried to use `gsub()`, but unfortunately that didn't work. I also found some sources, which suggested `cat()`, but that just prints my character, but does not store it in `x`.

2) Let's assume that I solved Question 1. Then my character would look like follows:

```
[1] "vjghvbh"kljnj"kjbn"jk"
```

Now I need to find the positions of the double quotes. Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249562/find-location-of-character-in-string) I tried `gregexpr()`. However, this also did not work, since I was not able to specify the `pattern`.

**Question 2: How could I find the position of the double quotes within my character string?**

The result in R should look like this:

```
[1] 8 14 19
```

Comment: Consider Q1 answered: `x <- 'vjghvbh"kljnj"kjbn"jk'` is correct and the string stored in `x` has no backslashes. `gregexpr('"', x, fixed=TRUE)[[1]]` will print the locations of matches.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Wiktor! If I run this code: `x <- 'vjghvbh"kljnj"kjbn"jk'`
`x`, then the output is: `[1] "vjghvbh\"kljnj\"kjbn\"jk"`. Could you elaborate, why it has no backslashes in your opinion?

Comment: It is not my opinion, there are no backslashes. It is not WYSIWYG. To define a backslash in a *string literal*, you must use ``\\``.

Comment: Are there no backslashes shown, if you run that code?

Comment: `cat(x, sep="\n")` -  no, no backslashes. Just what you need. See [**demo**](http://ideone.com/53kbQs). The question is a dupe. Lots of people are baffled by this.

Comment: Count the characters in `x`, then compare with the output of `nchar(x)`.

Comment: As for Q2, `gregexpr('\\"', x)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ Rui Barradas! That worked. Happy to give you credit if you formulate an answer!

Comment: 2 questions, 2 dupe reasons. You need no pattern for `gregexpr`, you only need a *string literal* denoting a fixed string, `'"'` or `"\""` with the `fixed=TRUE` argument. You just do not need to involve any regex engine here.

Comment: Of course it works, same as in my [**demo**](http://ideone.com/53kbQs) above. However, `'\\"'` is the same as `'"'` when used as a regex pattern because an escaped double quote is matching a double quote. Read the [***documentation***](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html).