# grep does not show all the indices, only [1]1

Tags: r

grep always output [1]1, but not the real index

```
a = "d123  d123 d123 asdf asd D123"
grep("d", a)
[1] 1
```

There are several "d" in the variable a, but not all the indices are displayed. I tried http://rfunction.com/archives/1481 and it works.

Why the simple one does not?

It is supposed to be equivalent to

```
unlist(gregexpr("d",a)[1])
```

Comment: Judging by the answers, you should clarify what is meant by "index". In your linked example, it's the index of a vector, hence my answer. But you mean the position in the string, in which case Ronak's answer.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**: *I assumed from your linked example that index referred to a vector. But now that I run the second code example in your question, I see you want index = position in string. So @ronak-shah is correct, not me.*

I think you want:

```
a = c("d123",  "d123", "d123", "asdf", "asd", "D123")
```

since your current variable `a` is one string with length = 1.

Answer (score 2):

From ?`grep`

> grep(value = FALSE) returns a vector of the indices of the elements of x that yielded a match

For example see,

```
x <- c("abc", "ddddd", "ads", "ccc")

grep("d", x)
#[1] 2 3
```

This means that `x[2]` and `x[3]` have `d` in them irrespective of the number of `d`s in them.

Since you want position of `d`s in the string <s>`grep` isn't the right choice here</s>. You could do

```
which(strsplit(a, "")[[1]]=="d")
#[1]  1  7 12 19 24
```

and with `grep` it would be

```
grep("d", strsplit(a, "")[[1]])
#[1]  1  7 12 19 24
```

which would give you equivalent of `unlist(gregexpr("d",a)[1])`.

Or use any of the method given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249562/find-location-of-character-in-string) link.