# Tracing where the original character was

Tags: r, strsplit

I am trying to create a function where I can split a sequence of letters such as that shown below.

SCDKSFNRGECSCDKSFNRGECSCDKSFNRGEC

I want to be able to split the sequence after every C and can do that using the following code:

```
TestSequence <- "SCDKSFNRGECSCDKSFNRGECSCDKSFNRGEC"

test <- strsplit(TestSequence, "(?<=[C])", perl = TRUE )
```

printing provides the following after unlisting :
`"SC"        "DKSFNRGEC" "SC"        "DKSFNRGEC" "SC"        "DKSFNRGEC"`

However I would like to be able to trace the output C back to it's location in the original sequence, it would be useful for example if every letter had a number I could relate back to, like the initial SC, I'd be able to say that C was the first C in the total sequence, the next SC will have a C that is third in the sequence and so on.

Can anyone think of a way of being able to trace back where the split characters were in the original sequence? I'm sure there is a better way than I have suggested above.

Comment: How do you want the output to be?

Comment: Maybe this: `gregexpr("C", TestSequence)`? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/14249562/680068

Answer (score 0, accepted):

along these lines?

```
library(dplyr)

TestSequence <- "SCDKSFNRGECSCDKSFNRGECSCDKSFNRGEC"

fragments <- strsplit(TestSequence, "(?<=[C])", perl = TRUE) %>% unlist

data.frame(fragment = fragments) %>%
  mutate(position = cumsum(nchar(fragment)))
```

output:

```
##    fragment position
## 1        SC        2
## 2 DKSFNRGEC       11
## 3        SC       13
## 4 DKSFNRGEC       22
## 5        SC       24
## 6 DKSFNRGEC       33
```

Comment: That's great, exactly what I needed, thank you.

Comment: following on from this, if I wanted to split the sequence at a different letter, say after K, but still retain the position of the C within that sequence, do you know how to do that?

Comment: Along with the fragments produced with splitting by "K", do you want to record the absolute position of the "C"s (if any) along the whole string or each "C"s relative position(s) within the fragment? The former might get meddlesome.

Comment: The former, but like you said I realise it is going to be harder than the latter.
I need to keep the absolute position of the C with respect to the test sequence.